# Move to latest past datetime with given time using Pandas DateOffset

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given a datetime `x` I'd like to compute the latest previous datetime with a given time (`09:00` in my case). That is, if the time in `x` is later than `09:00` then I want to get a new datetime with the same date as `x` (and a time of `09:00`), and if the time in `x` is earlier than `09:00` then I want to get a new datetime pointing to `09:00` on the day before `x`.

Is this possible using `pandas.DateOffset`? I've tried

```
x + DateOffset(hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
```

and

```
x + DateOffset(days=-1, hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
```

but the first doesn't work correctly if `x` is before `09:00` (it moves the time forwards), and the latter doesn't work correctly if `x` is after `09:00` (it moves to the previous day).

I know how to do this "manually", but I'd like to reuse existing code that would force me to do this via `DateOffset`.

Comment: Are you asking to manipulate a pd.Series or just a datetime variable?

Comment: @QuangHoang: I'd prefer a solution that works with both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use twice `pd.Dateoffset`, first remove 9 hours and then set the hour to 9 with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.to_datetime(['2019-09-20 08:34:21', '2019-09-20 09:34:21',])})
print(df.a + pd.DateOffset(hours=-9) + pd.DateOffset(hour=9, minute=0, second=0))
0   2019-09-19 09:00:00
1   2019-09-20 09:00:00
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: While it doesn't work in particular case (I would only be able to use a single `DateOffset`) this is the closest answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is test hours:

```
out = x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(hour=9, minute=0, second=0) 
      if x.hour > 9 
      else x + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=-1, hour=9, minute=0, second=0)
```